# I'm typing a password on a console prompt, and do typo errors: how to reset from scratch what I'm typing?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, password, console

`password:`
and here, after few characters, I understand that I've done a lot of typing errors.

But I don't know how to reset what I'm typing in this input field from scratch, to restart again, except by hitting the backspace key a lot of times...

What's the shortcut to reset my password content, to retype it from scratch, before submitting it?

Comment: Thanks. To answer the question, it's Ctrl-u, then.

Comment: I have several ctrl-u's in my password.